# Django : Query a model from it's save method

Tags: python, django

I want to override the save method in a model and from inside the save method, query the model itself. Can I access the `Student` model inside it's own method like it's done below?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50)    
    count  = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        count = Student.objects.filter(action=self.action).order_by('-count'))[:1]
        if count:
            #do something
        else:
            #do something else
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What's the difference between these 2 ways?

```
count = Student.objects.filter(...)
count = self.__class__.objects.filter(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st question**: Yes you can access a class in one of it's methods.

**2nd question**: In your example they are equivalent, but if you were to subclass it (called `SubStudent` for example), the first would still reference `Student` where `self.__class__` would reference `SubStudent`